# Is this PDO function safe from sql injection

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following insert function. Is it safe from a sql injection. If it isn't then how do I make it safe.

```
public function insert($postValues, $table){

    $dbh = $this->connect();

    try {
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $fields = implode(array_keys($postValues), ',');
        $values = "'".implode(array_values($postValues), "','")."'"; 
        $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$fields.') VALUES (:'.$fields.')';

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($insertQuery);

        foreach($postValues as $vals) {
            $stmt->execute($vals);
        }

        $message = $sucessMessage;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $message = $e->getMessage();
    }

    $dbh = null;

    return $message;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each column type is a `PDO::PARAM_STR`, then it is fairly simple to bind your parameters to unamed paramter markers using [PDOStatement::execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).  However, if the column types vary, then you need to specify the column type for each column when you bind to it with [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Accepting table and column names from what appears to be user input, is not a good idea.  The query will fail if the table or column names are incorrect, but you need to be very careful to ensure that the table and column names are safe to use. The following example checks the table and column names against a whitelist, prior to executing any SQL:

```
function insert($postValues, $table) {
    $dbh = $this->connect();

    // Create a simple whitelist of table and column names.
    $whitelist = array('my_table' => array('col1', 'col2', 'col3'));

    // Check if the table name exists in the whitelist.
    if(!array_key_exists($table, $whitelist)) {
        exit("$table is not a valid table name.\n");
    }

    // Count the number of columns that are found in the whitelist.
    $cols = count(
        array_intersect(
            $whitelist[$table],
            array_keys($postValues)));

    if($cols !== count($postValues)) {
        exit("One or more invalid column names have been supplied.\n");
    }

    // Create a comma separated list of column names.
    $columns = implode(', ', array_keys($postValues));
    // Create a comma separated list of unnamed placeholders.
    $params = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($postValues), '?'));
    // Create a SQL statement.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($params)";

    // Prepare the SQL statement.
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    // Bind the values to the statement, and execute it.
    return $stmt->execute(array_values($postValues));
}

echo insert(
    array(
        'col1' => 'value1',
        'col2' => 'value2',
        'col3' => 'value3'),
    'my_table');

// 1

echo insert(
    array(
        'col1' => 'value1',
        'col2' => 'value2',
        'col3' => 'value3'),
    'unsafe_table');

// unsafe_table is not a valid table name.

echo insert(
    array(
        'col1' => 'value1',
        'col2' => 'value2',
        'unsafe_col' => 'value3'),
    'my_table');

// One or more invalid column names have been supplied.
```

Answer (score 4):

The only sane way is to use [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with parameters (see example in manual). Moreover, field names should be taken from trusted source, i.e. not user. This way, you build your query string from trusted components:

```
function insert ($table, $fields, $data)
{
    $field_names = implode (", ", $fields);                      # "a, b"
    $values = ":" . implode (", :", $fields);                    # ":a, :b"
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table($field_names) VALUES($values)";
    $sth = $pdo->prepare ($query);

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        # Here you can even remove "bad" keys from $row
        $sth->execute ($row);
    }
}

$fields = array ('a', 'b'); # those are hard-coded in application
$data = array (             # those come from user
    array ('a'=>'Apple', 'b'=>'Bean'),
    array ('a'=>'Avocado', 'b'=>'Blueberry', '); DELETE FROM fruits; -- '=>'evil'),
);
insert ('fruits', $fields, $data);
```

Comment: Mike's answer is better in this case. The statement above executes as many queries as there are fields, which could range into the hundreds rather than a single INSERT query

Answer (score 1):

By the way: when asking if PDO is safer from sql injection than some other PHP MySQL connection library, the answer is **NO** when we talk about `PDO_MYSQL` (don't know if the following is true for some other databases).

One could even argue the other way round, PDO is less secure and more dangerous than any other PHP MySQL connection library (`ext/mysql` and `ext/mysqli`) because `PDO_MYSQL` allows for multiple queries in one SQL statement while `ext/mysql` stops multi-queries completely and `ext/mysqli` has a sparate function `mysqli_multi_query()`.

I just tried to find any sources to support this statement, but the only things I found are:

- [Protection against SQL Injection using PDO and Zend Framework](http://www.dotkernel.com/php-development/protection-against-sql-injection-using-pdo-and-zend-framework/)

  > PDO_MySQL is a more dangerous
  >   application than any other traditional
  >   MySQL applications. Traditional MySQL
  >   allows only a single SQL query. In
  >   PDO_MySQL there is no such limitation,
  >   but you risk to be injected with
  >   multiple queries.
- [Zend Webcast "Secure Application Development with the Zend Framework"](http://www.zend.com/webinar/Framework/70170000000bEs9-webinar-secure-application-development-with-the-ZF-20100505.flv) by Stefan Esser (slide 18)

Comment: That maybe so, but once you use prepared statements (as you should) that problem ceases to exist.

Answer (score -1):

No, because you're just executing a raw SQL query with the PDO extension. I do something similar to the following:

```
$fields = array();
$values = array();

foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
    $fields[] = $field;
    $values[] = $this->pdo->quote($value);
}

$fields = implode(',', $fields);
$values = implode(',', $values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
$res = $this->pdo->query($sql);
```

I'm sure you can modify the above to fit your set-up.

Comment: But, as can be read in the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php), you'd better use prepare(). You can easily dynamically create a sql string with placeholders and subsequentially call bindParam/bindValue to bind them to the statement.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Although if I loop over my `$_POST` data (or whatever array I'm using) I can also act upon data. For example, hash passwords before they're used in the query or the key/value pair completely if I'm updating and the user hasn't entered anything as their new password. If I didn't remove the key, then an empty string would be hashed and break the user's login. Just one scenario to think about.

Comment: @Dennis: Unfortunately you cannot easily bind array values to prepared statements. So the approach above is OK. Of course you can dynamically build the prepared SQL statement (adding as many placeholders as you require) and then bind each array item to this statement.

Comment: @Stefan: That's exactly what I am getting it. You could use array_walk() to keep it plain and simple, or you could use foreach() and still have full control.

Comment: Just realized that you're also building up the columns dynamically without doing some proper column-name-quoting. This is an absolute **no-go**. Take a POST variable name of `) VALUES (); DELETE FROM users WHERE 1=1; -- ` for example... This will result in the following query `INSERT INTO $table () VALUES (); DELETE FROM users WHERE 1=1; -- ) VALUES ($values)`.

Comment: It was a quick snippet wrote off-hand. Indeed, column names are properly quoted with back-ticks when I use PDO.